# What does dt in dt_socket stand for?

Tags: java, debugging, jpda

In the context of the [Java Platform Debugger Architecture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html), what does the `dt_` prefix in, for example, `dt_socket` or `dt_shmem` stand for?

Debugger transport?
Data transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dt stands for debugging transport. It is a prefix used for various debugging transport libraries in JPDA.